# Apollo v3 GraphQL Subscription Error: Must provide document

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

I'm testing out subscription on Apollo v3 using the example setup on the docs. But I get the above error. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here's the complete [reproducible code on Github gist](https://gist.github.com/Dajust/bce513fac1800a4e366d978f6c11f743)

```js
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Subscription {
    incremented: Int
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Subscription: {
    incremented: {
      subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator('NUMINCREMENTED'),
    },
  },
};

(async function () {
  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });

  const subscriptionServer = SubscriptionServer.create(
    {
      schema,
      execute,
      subscribe,
    },
    { server: httpServer }
  );

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    plugins: [
      {
        async serverWillStart() {
          return {
            async drainServer() {
              subscriptionServer.close();
            },
          };
        },
      },
    ],
  });
})();
```

Here's the error when I try the subscription on Apollo Studio.

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Downgrade apollo-server-express to 3.1.2.

Then everything should work.